# Valid Sudoku in Swift

Tags: programming-challenge, swift, sudoku

This is my solution to [LeetCode – Valid Sudoku](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-sudoku/) in Swift.

[image: img]

```
class Solution {
    func isValidSudoku(_ board: [[Character]]) -> Bool {
        let count = board.count


        var set = Set<Character>()
        for i in 0..<count{

            //  firstly
            set = Set(board[i])

            var num = board[i].reduce(0 , {(result : Int, char : Character)
                in
                var cent = 0
                if String(char) == "."{
                    cent = 1
                }
                return result + cent
            })

            if num > 0 , count - num != set.count - 1{
                return false
            }
            else if num == 0, set.count != count{
                return false
            }


            // secondly

            set = Set(board.reduce([Character]() , { resultArray, chars in
                return resultArray + [chars[i]]
            }))

            num = board.reduce(0 , {(result : Int, chars : [Character])
                in
                var cent = 0
                if String(chars[i]) == "."{
                    cent = 1
                }
                return result + cent
            })

            if num > 0 , count - num != set.count - 1{
                return false
            }
            else if num == 0, set.count != count{
                return false
            }



            // thirdly
            let characters = board.flatMap{
                return $0
            }


            let fisrtMiddle = ( i/3 ) * 27 + ( i % 3 ) * 3 + 1
            let secondMiddle = fisrtMiddle + 9
            let thirdMiddle = fisrtMiddle + 18
            let arrayThree = [characters[fisrtMiddle - 1], characters[fisrtMiddle], characters[fisrtMiddle + 1],
                                                       characters[secondMiddle - 1], characters[secondMiddle], characters[secondMiddle + 1],
                                                                                        characters[thirdMiddle - 1], characters[thirdMiddle], characters[thirdMiddle + 1]]
            set = Set(arrayThree)
            num = arrayThree.reduce(0 , {(result : Int, char : Character)
                in
                var cent = 0
                if String(char) == "."{
                    cent = 1
                }
                return result + cent
            })

            if num > 0 , count - num != set.count - 1{
                return false
            }
            else if num == 0, set.count != count{
                return false
            }
        }


        return true
    }
}
```

How can I make it shorter in syntax and keep intuitive, like the following Python code?

```
def isValidSudoku(self, board):
    seen = sum(([(c, i), (j, c), (i/3, j/3, c)]
                for i, row in enumerate(board)
                for j, c in enumerate(row)
                if c != '.'), [])
    return len(seen) == len(set(seen))
```

The Python code is very Pythonic and short.

How to use Swift syntax power to make my code shorter?

I think Functional is a good choice. RxSwift is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Naming

Some variable names should be more descriptive:

- What does `set` contain?
- What does `num` count?
- What is `cent` or `arrayThree`?

#### Simplifications

`if String(char) == "."` can be shorted to `if char == "."`, the conversion to
a string is not needed because `"."` can be both a string literal and a
character literal.

In

```
var num = board[i].reduce(0 , {(result : Int, char : Character)
    in
    var cent = 0
    if String(char) == "."{
        cent = 1
    }
    return result + cent
})
```

the closure can be shortened to

```
var num = board[i].reduce(0 , {(result, char) in
    char == "." ? result + 1 : result
})
```

without the need for a temporary variable.

In

```
set = Set(board.reduce([Character]() , { resultArray, chars in
    return resultArray + [chars[i]]
}))
```

an array is created with the elements in column #i, and put into a set. That can be simplified to

```
let column = board.map { $0[i]} // Column #i
set = Set(column)
```

and `column` can then also be used in the following count of empty fields.

The creation of an array of all entries of a block can be simplified using
array slices:

```
let firstRow = 3 * (i / 3)
let firstCol = 3 * (i % 3)
let block = board[firstRow..<firstRow+3].flatMap { $0[firstCol..<firstCol+3]}
```

Generally, the check for duplicate digits in a row/column/block can
be simplified if you filter out empty fields *before* creating the set,
that makes counting the empty fields obsolete.

#### Comments

The comments

```
// firstly
// secondly
// thirdly
```

are not really helpful.

#### Putting it together

Summarizing the above suggestions so far, the code could look like this:

```
class Solution {
    func isValidSudoku(_ board: [[Character]]) -> Bool {

        for i in 0..<9 {
            // Check digits in row #i:
            let rowDigits = board[i].filter { $0 != "." }
            if rowDigits.count != Set(rowDigits).count {
                return false
            }

            // Check digits in column #i:
            let colDigits = board.map { $0[i] }.filter { $0 != "." }
            if colDigits.count != Set(colDigits).count {
                return false
            }

            // Check digits in block #i:
            let firstRow = 3 * (i / 3)
            let firstCol = 3 * (i % 3)
            let blockDigits = board[firstRow..<firstRow+3].flatMap { $0[firstCol..<firstCol+3]}
                .filter { $0 != "." }
            if blockDigits.count != Set(blockDigits).count {
                return false
            }       
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

#### An alternative approach

The Python solution can not be translated directly to Swift, one reason is
that tuples are not `Hashable` and therefore cannot be put into a set.
Also inhomogeneous collections are better avoided in Swift.

But we *can* enumerate the board in a similar fashion, and put each element
into a set corresponding to its row, column, and block. The return value
from the `insert` statement already indicates if an identical element was
already present.

That leads to the following implementation:

```
class Solution {
    func isValidSudoku(_ board: [[Character]]) -> Bool {
        var rowSets = Array(repeating: Set<Character>(), count: 9)
        var colSets = Array(repeating: Set<Character>(), count: 9)
        var blockSets = Array(repeating: Set<Character>(), count: 9)

        for (i, row) in board.enumerated() {
            for (j, char) in row.enumerated() where char != "." {
                if !rowSets[i].insert(char).inserted {
                    return false
                }
                if !colSets[j].insert(char).inserted {
                    return false
                }
                let block = (i / 3) + 3 * (j / 3)
                if !blockSets[block].insert(char).inserted {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

I haven't checked which one is more efficient, I leave that task to you :)

Comment: The latter one gets better performance.  It takes 316 ms to pass 504 test case in Leetcode.   And the prior one takes 356 ms. It is heard that  `functional languages are a bad fit for high performance computing: they’re high-level, rely on garbage collection, are pretty inflexible about memory layouts and don’t permit all the low-level optimizations you need to maximize performance.`

Comment: Wondering where to find the syntax ‘set.inserted’ . I did not googled it yet. And not see it in [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set). And it works

Comment: @dengApro: That overview page does not show the return values of the methods. If you go to [`Set.insert(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1541375-insert) then you see that the method returns a tuple whose first member `.inserted` indicates if the member was already present or not.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative solution

Here is the (current) fastest solution. It is pretty straightforward :

**1-** First off, let's model the Sudoku grid :
A row is a set of unique digits from 0 to 9, represented by characters. The rows all together, will be represented by an array of those sets :

```
var rows = Array(repeating: Set<Character>(), count: 9)
```

`rows` is mutable since we'll be filling those initially empty sets.

**2-** The same goes for the columns :

```
var columns = Array(repeating: Set<Character>(), count: 9)
```

**3-** A 3x3 box will be modeled by a set of characters. Three boxes on the same horizontal line will be represented by an array of 3 boxes (3 sets of characters). 3 of those arrays make a whole Sudoku grid :

```
var boxes = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: Set<Character>(), count: 3), count: 3)
```

**4-** Then, we loop through all the "rows" and "columns" inside of `board` :

```
for row in 0..<9 {
    for column in 0..<9 {
        let value = board[row][column]
        ...
    }
}
```

**5-** If a cell is not empty :

```
let value = board[row][column]

if value != "." {
    ...
}
```

**6-** ... we try to insert it into a cell. A cell belongs to a row, a column, and a box. Three checks have to be made: If either the row, or the column, or the box already contains that character, return `false`.

To do this we use the pretty handy `inserted` element from the tuple returned by the [`insert(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1541375-insert) method :

```
if !rows[row].insert(value).inserted
    || !columns[column].insert(value).inserted
    || !boxes[row/3][column/3].insert(value).inserted {
    return false
}
```

---

Here is the complete solution :

```
class Solution {
    func isValidSudoku(_ board: [[Character]]) -> Bool {
        var rows = Array(repeating: Set<Character>(), count: 9)
        var columns = Array(repeating: Set<Character>(), count: 9)
        var boxes = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: Set<Character>(), count: 3), count: 3)

        for row in 0..<9 {
            for column in 0..<9 {
                let value = board[row][column]

                if value != "." {
                    if !rows[row].insert(value).inserted
                        || !columns[column].insert(value).inserted
                        || !boxes[row/3][column/3].insert(value).inserted {
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

It's execution time is `204 ms` on LeetCode :

[image: 100%]

Compared to `212 ms` for the alternative approach given in the accepted answer (which is faster than 70.73%)

---

### Playing golf

If you're looking for a short, *Pythony*, solution, (not necessarily the fastest), then here is a solution :

```
class Solution {
    func isValidSudoku(_ board: [[Character]]) -> Bool {
        var seen: [String] = []
        for (i, row) in board.enumerated() {
            for case let (j, c) in row.enumerated() where c != "." {
                seen.append(contentsOf: ["r\(i)\(c)", "c\(j)\(c)", "b\(i/3)\(j/3)\(c)"])
            }
        }
        return seen.count == Set(seen).count
    }
}
```